# variable declaration conditional syntax

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax, d3.js

I was looking some great d3.js [code examples](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2706022) when I saw something like:

```
var links = [
  {source: "test1", target: "test2"},
  {source: "test1", target: "test3"},
  {source: "test2", target: "test3"},
  {source: "test3", target: "test4"}
];

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});
```

I didn't get immediately how the var nodes was being declared.

My first guess was to translate it into:

```
links.forEach(function(link) {
  if(link.source != nodes[link.source]){
    nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source};
  }
  if(link.target != nodes[link.target]){
    nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target};
  }
});
```

But the links are not drawn anymore.

What is the difference between the two methods?

What is the point of the initial syntax, is that just a shortcut or do it increase performances?

Is there a best practice to follow in such cases ?

**Edit**

So if I try to fully understand

```
link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
```

1. As *nodes[link.source]* is an object *link.source* takes its reference. This is always happening.
2. OR condition, I'm not sure to get that part.

   I guess if *nodes[link.source]* is defined *link.source = nodes[link.source]* return true we don't need go further.

   If it's not defined and return false, the OR clause force to go further...
3. *nodes[link.source]* gets a value so thanks to the reference *link.source* is pointing to the same value.

   I guess at this stage *link.source* is not yet containing a reference to *nodes[link.source]*, but its initial value. It will contain the new reference after the comma.

Am I wrong somewhere ? Point 2 seems strange to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code used in the example is simply a syntactial shortcut. It is equivalent to

```
links.forEach(function(link) {
  if(nodes[link.source]) { // we already know about the source of this link
    link.source = nodes[link.source];
  } else { // we haven't seen this source before, create a new node for it
    nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source};
    link.source = nodes[link.source];
  }

  if(nodes[link.target]) { // we already know about the target of this link
    link.target = nodes[link.target];
  } else { // we haven't seen this target before, create a new node for it
    nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target};
    link.target = nodes[link.target];
  }
});
```

All of this is necessary because the nodes are only declared implicitly through the links -- that is, there's no list of nodes, it is only assembled by traversing the links and "harvesting" the sources and targets. This is what's stored in `nodes` -- it's a mapping from the ID of the node (from the links) to the object representing the node.

The code above simultaneously populates this map by creating new objects for unseen nodes (i.e. ones which are not present in the mapping) and inserting the respective mapping. The sources and targets of the links are then updated to point to those objects (which will later be operated on by the force layout to set their positions) instead of the ID of the node as referenced in the original data.

Edit: Your edited interpretations are correct. This is basically what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
```

Can be translated to:

```
if(!nodes[link.source]) {
    nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source};
}
link.source = nodes[link.source];
```

*(Same thing with `link.target`)*.

So:

```
var links = [
  {source: "test1", target: "test2"},
  {source: "test1", target: "test3"},
  {source: "test2", target: "test3"},
  {source: "test3", target: "test4"}
];
```

would be transformed to:

```
links = [
  {source: { name: "test1" }, target: { name: "test2" }},
  {source: { name: "test1" }, target: { name: "test3" }},
  {source: { name: "test2" }, target: { name: "test3" }},
  {source: { name: "test3" }, target: { name: "test4" }}
];
```

and nodes will be equal to:

```
nodes = {
    "test1": { name: "test1" },
    "test2": { name: "test2" },
    "test3": { name: "test3" },
    "test4": { name: "test4" },
}
```

Comment: The outer check `if(link.source != nodes[link.source]) {` isn't actually necessary in this case (and not present in the original code).

Comment: It's implicit (`link.source` should be equal to `nodes[link.source]` in the end) and will prevent from setting `link.source = nodes[link.source];` more than one time for duplicate values.

Comment: It's a map -- not sure how you would get duplicate values in there? And no, it's not implicit. The original code would make multiple assignments if there were duplicate values.

Comment: I'm talking about `links` where `source` is equal to `test1` multiple times which will result in `link.source = nodes[link.source];` called multiple times if I remove the outer check. The original was a shortcut code so it's obvious that expanding it can be in many different ways and may result in different code if optimization is needed (the result must stay exactly the same of course).

Comment: Ah, but `link` is inside a loop, so will point to a different object every time. This block of code won't be executed several times with `link` being the same object.

Comment: You are right, I got confused by I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

my understanding to

```
link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
```

is, if `nodes[link.source]` doesn't exist

then just do `link.source = nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source};`