# Understanding code for computing the distinct nodes from the links

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can someone help me understand what the following code snippet from [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8043434) does

```
// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
   link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
   link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
   link.value = +link.value;
});
```

I've seen it used in a few different implementations of directional force layout but I'm unclear how the shorthand works or accomplishes it's goal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain Mike Bostock Node-Parsing Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45974522/explain-mike-bostock-node-parsing-loop) itself being a duplicate of [variable declaration conditional syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930335/variable-declaration-conditional-syntax).